Cohomological characterization of when $f: \pi_1(\Sigma_g) \to P$ factors through $F_g$ when $P$ is perfect
In previous questions on this site such as this one, it has been asked when a map $\varphi \colon G \to H$ of finitely generated groups factors through a free quotient meaning that there exists a surjective homomorphisms $\psi \colon G \to F_k$ and $f \colon F_k \to H$ such that $\varphi = f \circ \psi$ where $F_k$ is the free group of rank $k$.  If we know for instance that $G$ and $H$ have the same rank, then this is impossible because we would then contradict the fact that free groups are Hopfian. Another necessary condition is that the map $\varphi^*\colon H^i(H,M) \to H^i(G,M)$ is trivial for $i>1$ and for all $H$ modules which follows from the fact that free groups have cohomological dimension $1$. Finally, we know that a homomorphism $\varphi \colon G \to H$ factors through a free group if and only if there is a normal subgroup $N \leq \ker(\varphi)$ such that $G \cong N \rtimes F_k$. I have been doing a literature search and have not been able to find anything other than what I have mentioned. So it seems that this question is hard in general.
I am interested in a very specific example. Let $g \geq 3$, and let $\varphi \colon \pi_1(\Sigma_g) \to P$ be a surjective homomorphism to a perfect group whose rank is $g$ or less and where $H_2(P,\mathbb{Z}) = 0$. Since $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$ has cohomological dimension $2$, the map $\varphi^* \colon H^i(Q, M) \to H^i(\pi_1(\Sigma_g), M)$ is trivial for all $i>2$ and $P$-modules $M$. Additionally, since $H_2(P, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$, we can use the universal coefficient theorem to show that $H^1(P, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ and $H^2(P,\mathbb{Z}) = 0$. In particular, we have $\varphi^* \colon H^i(P, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^i(\pi_1(\Sigma_g), \mathbb{Z})$ is the trivial map for all $i>0$. This map has no cohomological obstructions as far as I can tell, but that doesn't immediately mean that the homomorphism factors through a surjection onto the free group $F_g$.
I have two questions:

Under these conditions does the homomorphism $\varphi$ factor through the free group?
If the question to the above question is no, are there finer homological or algebraic invariants that obstructs

Any insight that anyone can provide on these questions would be greatly helpful.

I don't think that vanishing 1st and 2nd integral homology implies vanishing 1st and 2nd arbitrary cohomology. There are acyclic groups with nontrivial cohomology (such as Higman's group which has cohomological dimension 2).

Oh I must have made a mistake. Let me update to cohomology with integral coefficients

For $G$ an arbitrary finite group, it follows from work of Dunfield and Thurston that any map $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)\to G$ factors through the handlebody group $F_g$ if the obvious homological obstruction in $H_2(G, \mathbb Z)$ vanishes and $g$ is sufficiently large with respect to $G$. The case without the large $g$ assumption seems very difficult.

I guess $Q$ is a typo for $P$ in your second paragraph? Also, groups $P$ for which $H_1(P;\mathbb{Z})=H_2(P;\mathbb{Z})=0$ are called superperfect. So you are asking about superperfect quotients of surface groups.
